# log4j property change not getting reflected in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

This was the log4j file I used for my project till I checked in my project to a SVN repository. This was working fine and I saw log information on Eclipse's console

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %p %t %C.%M (%F:%L) %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=x.log

 log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
 # Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %p %t %C.%M (%F:%L) %m%n
```

I checked out my project from repository and disabled logging by making this change in my log4j property file.

```
#log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

But this change didn't work as expected, I still got the log information on Eclipse's console. When I cross checked the same on Terminal, it was fine, I didn't get log info on Terminal. Any problem with Eclipse? I searched a lot on this issue, didn't get any solution. Help me in finding out what's wrong here!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible issues here:

1. the configuration should say (to tell it no appenders, instead of looking for OFF appender):

   log4j.rootLogger=
2. Eclipse is using an old version of the file, likely because you edited the file outside of Eclipse. Just refresh the file (Right click / Refresh) and it should start working as you expect.

Comment: ya I fixed it prob was I had log4j property file in another project, eclipse was using that, when I disabled logging in that file, I got the expected result thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-Dlog4j.debug` property to output log4j-internal debugging information and see which logging configuration is really loaded on startup

You will get some information like this (for xml based configuration but I suppose you will get similar informations with property file configurations):

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/develop/workspace/foobar/target/classes/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
```

The `'log4j: Using URL ...'` line comes from the [LogManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.8/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.java) class.

Comment: ya I fixed it prob was I had log4j property file in another project, eclipse was using that, when I disabled logging in that file, I got the expected result thanks for your help :)